# .delay preventing fadeIn from executing

Tags: jquery, delay, fadein

I can't seem to figure out why this piece of script will work as expected, when the ".delay(800)" is removed...but with it in, the fadeIn that follows ".delay(800)" is never executed. Any idea why?

**CSS**

```
#stepone, #steptwo, #stepthree, #stepfour, #stepfive, #finish  {
display:none;
}
```

**jQuery Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#startbutton").click(function() {
        $("#stepone, #steptwo, #stepthree, #stepfour, #stepfive, #finish").fadeOut(800);
        $("#start").delay(800).fadeIn(800);
    });
    $("#steponebutton").click(function() {
        $("#start, #steptwo, #stepthree, #stepfour, #stepfive, #finish").fadeOut(800);
        $("#stepone").delay(800).fadeIn(800);
    });
});
```

Comment: If you can recreate this in fiddle.net, it makes it easier for us to help :)

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dtAum/

Comment: Can you post your html as well?

Comment: For sure; should have started that way. =)  Give me 2 minutes, and I'll put it together!

Comment: Well hum-de-dum...seems to be working alright here: http://jsfiddle.net/nbr8C/

Comment: Any ideas on what might be causing that? Something else in the CSS? "display" issues, maybe?